# How do I create this complicated table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

[image]

Having a hard time creating this table in latex, any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. Please tell us what you’ve tried so far. (Postings that show minimal or no research effort tend to attract few answers.)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! This is not a complicated table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*7{c|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Compression failure} \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Group 1} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Afternoon}\\
\hline
Test & Load & Stress & Pattern & Load & Stress & Pattern \\
\hline
 & [lb]& [psi] & & [lb]& [psi] & \\
\hline 
 1 & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$\\
\hline 
 2 & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$\\
\hline 
 3 & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$\\
\hline 
 Avg & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$ & $123,567$\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously I had not the patience to punch in your data from the screen shot.

Notice that nowadays there is a trend to use `bookmarks` and less lines, in particular no vertical lines, to use `siunitx` to align the numbers at the period or comma and so on and so forth. I guess these are the first steps in rethinking the need of such tables completely, in an age in which data gets usually accessed and processed electronically. That is, if you really need such a table consider using e.g. `pgfplotstable` and typeset it automatically from some data file while computing the average and so on for you. Also, please do not post screen shots because this forces the one writing an answer punching in stuff from a screen shot.

Comment: What do you think of https://mathpix.com/ for that kind of cases?

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb I don't know anything about it but IMHO the best tables are avoided tables. Who really reads the contents of these in detail? At best a few. And then it makes IMHO no big difference if there are vertical lines or not. There are. of course, tables that get read, but they contain some dynamical data and are typically posted on web sites.

Comment: A good image vs dull tables indeed. Take a look at this start up, they use IA and the result saves so much time for tables, as well as equation writing.

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Yes, there was some progress in data visualization from Gutenberg's days till now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that difficult, actually. I fixed the units: they should be in parentheses like (lb), not in brackets like [lb].

Just remember that headers in S columns should be braced.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}% for the numbers

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Summary of compressive strength, 7-day results}\label{A}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{
  |c|
  S[table-format=3.3]|
  S[table-format=1.3]|
  c|
  S[table-format=2.3]|
  S[table-format=1.3]|
  c|
}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Compressive failure} \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Group 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Afternoon} \\
\hline
Test & {Load} & {Stress} & {Pattern} & {Load} & {Stress} & {Pattern} \\
\hline
& {(lb)} & {(psi)}  &           & {(lb)} & {(psi)}  &           \\
\hline
%
1   & 101,522 & 3,525 & 2 & 85,667 & 3,063 & 2 \\
\hline
2   &  95,365 & 3,334 & 5 & 84,003 & 3,012 & 2 \\
\hline
3   &  90,759 & 3,253 & 2 & 87,969 & 3,152 & 2 \\
\hline
Avg &  95,881 & 3,371 &   & 85,879 & 3,075 &   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### And now, for something completely different.

[image]

Please, compare the two outputs and choose.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}% for the numbers
\usepackage{booktabs}% for the better table

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Summary of compressive strength, 7-day results}\label{A}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  c
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  c
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  c
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Compressive failure} \\
\midrule
Test & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Group 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Afternoon} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
& {Load (lb)} & {Stress (psi)} & {Pattern} & {Load (lb)} & {Stress (psi)} & {Pattern} \\
\midrule
%
1   & 101,522 & 3,525 & 2 & 85,667 & 3,063 & 2 \\
2   &  95,365 & 3,334 & 5 & 84,003 & 3,012 & 2 \\
3   &  90,759 & 3,253 & 2 & 87,969 & 3,152 & 2 \\
\midrule
Avg &  95,881 & 3,371 &   & 85,879 & 3,075 &   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```